# Can I insert the variables of the array into php include using a loop? Or is there another way?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Can I insert the variables of the array into php include using a loop? Or is there another way? i'm just tried
[here my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiveX.png)

Comment: Please see [ask] and http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Just try it out, but maybe not in single quotes + an extra semicolon at the end of the line;

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes when getting a variable's value, and yes it will work, another thing is to get the good habit on using `include_once` and `require_once` instead of `include` and `require`

```
include_once $path;
```